# how to get the token transaction history via web3.js (0.20.6)

Tags: web3js, erc-20, javascript, ethereumjs

set up

node.js
+ web3.js (0.20.6 version)
+ and using infura for the httpProvider

I've figured out and successfully sent erc20 tokens using the web3.js,
(after a lot of googling... complete noobie here...)

and i'm now trying to figure out how to get the the token transaction history of a specific address.

i get the idea that i need to watch the events,
which for token transactions, would be "Transfer" event.

so i'm following the Javascript-API for "contract events"
https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-events

and below is the code i'm running (or at least trying to)

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://rinkeby.infura.io/MYINFURATOKEN'));

var myaddress = "0x482d42bc7a5dd62f3fae88c3b4cde29a333cf913";

var contractAddress = "0x31a86307bfe81780a47fe98c192004ccdce8fcc0";

var abi = [{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"enableTokenTransfer","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"burn","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"TransferAllowed","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"frozenAccount","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"},{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"disableTokenTransfer","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"target","type":"address"},{"name":"freeze","type":"bool"}],"name":"freezeAccount","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"transferOwnership","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"initialSupply","type":"uint256"},{"name":"tokenName","type":"string"},{"name":"tokenSymbol","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"target","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"frozen","type":"bool"}],"name":"FrozenFunds","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"","type":"bool"}],"name":"TransferEnabled","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"","type":"bool"}],"name":"TransferDisabled","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Burn","type":"event"}];

var myContractInstance = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(contractAddress);

var event = myContractInstance.Transfer({_from: myaddress}, {fromBlock:0, toBlock: 'latest'});

event.watch(function(error, result){
  if (!error)
    console.log(result);
});
```

and that returns

```
Filter {
  requestManager: 
   RequestManager {
     provider: 
      HttpProvider {
        host: 'https://rinkeby.infura.io/MYINFURATOKEN',
        timeout: 0,
        user: undefined,
        password: undefined,
        headers: undefined },
     polls: {},
     timeout: null },
  options: 
   { topics: 
      [ '0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef',
        null,
        null ],
     from: undefined,
     to: undefined,
     address: '0x31a86307bfe81780a47fe98c192004ccdce8fcc0',
     fromBlock: '0x0',
     toBlock: 'latest' },
  implementation: 
   { newFilter: { [Function: send] request: [Function: bound ], call: [Function: newFilterCall] },
     uninstallFilter: { [Function: send] request: [Function: bound ], call: 'eth_uninstallFilter' },
     getLogs: { [Function: send] request: [Function: bound ], call: 'eth_getFilterLogs' },
     poll: { [Function: send] request: [Function: bound ], call: 'eth_getFilterChanges' } },
  filterId: null,
  callbacks: [ [Function] ],
  getLogsCallbacks: [],
  pollFilters: [],
  formatter: [Function: bound ] }
```

which i'm pretty sure isn't the token transaction history...
or is there a step that i'm missing?

how would i go from here?

Thank you in advance. 
Justin.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is *[past events](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#getpastevents)* i believe.

Comment: well "getPastEvents" is only for the web3 1.0.0, which is in beta...
I would rather use the stable version which is the 0.20.6 right now, and does not offer "getPastEvents"

Comment: I'd recommend checking out the source code and implementing yourself if you are hoping to stay on the stable version. You can find it here: https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/blob/40974e9fe9a8f9075fcbb4c002430c6480d83031/packages/web3-eth-contract/src/index.js#L782

Note: as of writing, the getPastEvents method is stable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing the same thing as you here.. 
This does show you the token transactions history, the thing is, it doesn't show you the history of a token transaction of a specific address.